# How to add the search form in Bootstrap theme?

Tags: 7, theming

I am trying to set the search form with submit button in the Navbar as shown in the following image(Following image I have taken from the [Bootstrap tutorial page](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)).

> [image]

---

- Now, When we install the default [Bootstrap theme](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap) from drupal.org it will be ended up like as shown in following image.

  > [image]

  Now, if I simply move that block to the Navigation bar, it will end
  up as shown in following image, which is not a solution for this.

  [image]

  So, I dig out on the [bootstrap tutorial
  page](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-forms) and found the
  following code.

  > [image]

  So, I can paste that code in the *page.tpl.php* and can achieve as
  shown in following image, BUT it will not search anything, as it is
  just a plain HTML code.

  [image]

---

How can I achieve that? If CSS is the answer, for now I do not want to go with that. As IMHO, since this display of search form is described as a default on the bootstrap tutorial and in every theme demo display pages, So, there should be some way to enable that, or some way to place that.

Any suggestion or direction? Thanks.

Comment: how about creating your own search block with custom tpl with that markup? in button and textfield you can add attribute class, placeholder

Comment: @iamroald I am thinking in that direction also. I have just added the answer and what is the issue, if you can suggest to fine-tune. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

After some search I figure out the following solution, it is working, But the issue is it is applying to `search_block_form` also, might be function `lsubtheme_bootstrap_search_form_wrapper($variables)` is the reason, which is getting applied everywhere. Might be giving False positive result.

**PLEASE anybody have any suggestion, how to imptove this, I am trying will update.**

**Codes in *template.php***

```
function lsubtheme_preprocess_page(&$variables){
  $search_form = drupal_get_form('search_form');
  $search_box = drupal_render($search_form);
  $variables['search_box'] = $search_box;
}

/*
 *  Form alter to add missing bootstrap classes and role to search form.
 */

function lsubtheme_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'search_form') {
    $form['#attributes']['class'][] = 'navbar-form navbar-left';
    $form['#attributes']['role'][] = 'search';
  }
}


function lsubtheme_bootstrap_search_form_wrapper($variables) {

  $output = '<div class="form-group">';
  $output .= $variables['element']['#children'];
  $output .= ' <div class="form-group">';
  $output .= '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>';
  $output .= '</div>';
  $output .= '</div>';
  return $output;
}
```

**Code in *page.tpl.php***

```
 <?php print $search_box; ?>
```

> [image]

Answer (score 2):

You will basically have to re-implement the rendering yourself.

The best way to do this, to me, is to implement hook_theme, provide a function, template, and variables to pass on, and change (via hook_form_alter or your provider Form class if you have one, Drupal 8) the form rendering function to your new one.

This will result in a cleaner more manageable approach, as you can then drop the HTML from the Bootstrap docs into your designated template. Then, any time you want to render a basic search form to be the Bootstrap one, change the forms `#theme` to your function. Then you don't have to fool with a lot of spaghetti code.

I would not copy/paste HTML into page.tpl.php as that will have no effect at all.

I see where you are getting the above code from, but I personally would not store markup like that in template.php. Easy to miss, and hard to adjust. The goal for an override like this is to isolate the behavior and ensure that no other form later on is inadvertently altered.

I wish I had an example on hand, but I cannot find one at the moment.

Comment: I will surely follow your steps. It will be some hard for me as currently I can play with some code logics, but not all. But I will try to do that. If you get any example please post it, so I can have something to apply the logic. Could you please see the following mine answer, Are you talking THAT kind of thing?, where I tried to do something like this **First**, Applied `preprocess` so `$search_box` will be accessible in `page`  **Second** applied the `class` and `role` for `search_form`. **Third** added HTML through hook. And then print the `$search_box` in `page.tpl.php`. Very thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why not solve this on the theme level? Add the following to your sub theme javascript file. See https://www.drupal.org/node/304255 for more info

```
jQuery('#search-block-form .input-group button.btn.btn-primary span')
  .text('Submit')
  .removeClass('glyphicon glyphicon-search icon')
```

Or in a new javascript file like

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var $button = jQuery('#search-block-form .input-group button.btn.btn-primary span');
  $button
    .text('Submit')
    .removeClass('glyphicon glyphicon-search icon');
  });
```

Resulting in [image]
I've tried other solutions in projects which never were more satisfying than this.

To test without sub theme I placed it in a module dummy hook_init().

```
/**
 * Implements hook_init().
 */
function dummy_init() {
    drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function () { jQuery("#search-block-form .input-group button.btn.btn-primary span").text("Submit").removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-search icon") });', 'inline');
}
```

Comment: Hi, I did not get your answer, suppose if I have to make a module of this code, other-way I can simply put it in `template.php` and give the functionaname `function myThemeName_init() {....code.....}`. But this way I found two issues, (1) The code seems somewahat buggy, as it is behaving like  one full `string`. (2) Suppose if the code is Ok, how it will show the Search form to `nav-bar`, would you like to explain more? btw, I have not downvoted. Thank for your try.

Comment: I assumed you are working on a subtheme where you can add the javascript snippet to your javascript file

Comment: I've updated the code and tested it on a sub theme. Works like a charm

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, Appreciated. What your code is doing, it providing the text `Submit` and hiding the `icon`. And second part in your answer should be talk about the placing the `Search form` in the `nav-bar` or placing the `$search_form` in the page.tpl.php. That all thing my answer is also doing. The purpose of my question was not just adding the search form in nav-bar, that I can done just placing the block there and use some CSS, but to find out how to do this right way in Drupal bootstrap theme. Continue.......

Comment: ....By saying this I mean, Bootstrap theme is the very well established theme and it has all sort of documentation, and if you see  that part of mentioned bootstrap documentation in my question, it has well mentioned code for the search form. And that theme has the official documentation for that drupal theme at [Drupal Bootstrap theme](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap). So if I aggregate all these facts, Bootstrap is not the native Drupal theme, Bootstrap is the basic HTML/CSS/JS theme for all platforms, hence, it deal with pure HTML, CSS, JS...Continue..

Comment: ...Hence when Drupal Bootstrap theme would have been created, it could have been well thought that people need to change or add the HTML as it is the basic thing to apply bootstrap theme features. Hence, from all this facts there should be a standard way to add the `search form` HTML code which is provided on the bootstrap tutorial site. That I'm looking for. Sorry for long explanation, I hope, you understand what I want to say. I appreciate your effort, so I will award you the bounty points, but I will not accept it as a answer as I want to keep this question open till I find the solution.Thx

Comment: I understand you concerns. The bootstrap Drupal 7 developers did a great job bridge the gap which was not easy. See their *.inc files. Thanks for the bounty :)